# Progressbar в wpf и асинхронном режиме

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем здравствуйте.Встала задача отобразить процесс выполнения операции, седлал все работает, но только  когда все в обычном режиме , не в асинхронном. Вот код простого примера. Задача, как сделать так,чтобы при выполнении команды в асинхронном режиме, прогрессбар работал.

Модель

```
 public delegate void StatusChangedHandler(int status);

        public class Model
        {
            private int start;
            private int end = 100;
            public event StatusChangedHandler StatusChange;

            public int Startbar
            {
                get { return start; }

                set
                {
                    start = value;
// при вызове команды асинхронно, событие становиться равным null всегда
                    StatusChange?.Invoke(value);
                }
            }

            public int End
            {
                get { return end; }

                set
                {
                    end = value;
                }
            }

            public int Go()
            {


                    // просто метод
                    Startbar = 0;
                    while (Startbar < End)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Startbar++;
                    }

                return Startbar;
            }


        }
```

ModelView

```
   class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            Model.Model _model = new Model.Model();

            private int _startbar;
            private int _endbar = 100;

            // реализую интерфейс
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            //[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            // команда запуска
            public ICommand CommandToPars
            {
                get
                {
                    return new DelegateCommand(async () =>
                    {
                        // выполняю метод, допустим асинхронно 
//  в этом случае прогресс бар не работает.
                       await _model.Go();
                        // забираю свойства
                        // праивльно ли так делать?
                        _model.StatusChange += _model_StatusChange;
                        _endbar = _model.End;

                    });

                }
            }

            private void _model_StatusChange(int status)
            {
                Startbar = status;
            }


            // свойства для прогресбара
            public int Startbar
            {
                get { return _startbar; }

                set
                {
                    _startbar = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public int Endtbar
            {
                get { return _endbar; }

                set
                {
                    _endbar = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
            public MainViewModel()
            {
            }
        }
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="progresbar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:progresbar"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="787.874" Width="800">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="345" Margin="10,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="747">
        <Button Command="{ Binding CommandToPars}" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="42" Margin="173,279,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="389"/>
        <ProgressBar  Maximum="{Binding Endtbar}"   Minimum="0" 
                      Value="{Binding Startbar}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" Margin="94,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="512"/>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="277" Margin="41,379,0,-311" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="673" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
                <Path StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
                      Stroke="Orange"
                      StrokeThickness="5">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <PathGeometry>
                            <PathFigure
                                StartPoint="{Binding StartPoint}" >
                                <ArcSegment
                                    x:Name="Whatup"
                                    Point="{Binding EndPoint}"
                                    Size="{Binding Size}"
                                    RotationAngle="0"
                                    IsLargeArc="{Binding IsLarge}"
                                    SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                                />
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathGeometry>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: вы нам задание даете переписать код так, как вам надо? Может, для начала сами попробуете решить вашу задачу?

Comment: нет , я уже с утра сижу думаю над этим, вариантов, пока нет рабочих у меня, я понимаю, вопрос именно в отложенном выполнении, отсюда и событие нулевое, Куда смотреть, чтобы найти решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы ожидать асинхронно надо использовать `Task.Delay` внутри асинхронного метода, например

```
        public async Task Go()
        {
                // просто метод
                Startbar = 0;
                while (Startbar < End)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(100);
                    Startbar++;
                }

            return Startbar;
        }
```

....

```
_model.StatusChange += _model_StatusChange;
_endbar = _model.End;
await _model.Go();
_model.StatusChange -= _model_StatusChange;
```

Comment: Спасибо,а какой смысл в отписки от события?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch 1) чтобы не держать ссылку на ViewModel почем зря 2) Если подписаться 10 раз и не отписываться, то одно событие будет 10 раз обрабатываться вашей VM

Comment: Спасибо очень ценно

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch пожалуйста

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а как можно обнулить прогрессбар,чтобы он снова скинулся в нулевые значения, я имею ввиду сам индикатор?

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch вы же прибиндили его к StartBar? Обнулите этот StartBar и в модели обнулить не забудтье

Comment: Да спасибо большое